# How to create a function to calculate the frequency of a character in a piece of text in python?

Tags: python, function, python-2.7

I need to create a function that counts the frequency of an inputed letter in a piece of text...

e.g.

```
import urllib

pieceoftext =urllib.urlopen(blahblahblah).read()

def frequency(char):
count = 0
for character in pieceoftext:
        count += 1
return count
```

...

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: well i know this "print pieceoftext.count('a')" gets my answer but I need to make a function to do it...

Comment: Then make it a function. Try defining a function with two parameters: your text, and the letter to count. Then fill it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def frequency(char, sentence):
    count = 0
    for k in list(sentence):
        if k == char:
            count+=1
    return count
```

This runs as:

```
frequency('t', 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.')
2
```

`list(sentence)` gets each individual character in the sentence, which we loop over with a `for` loop. We then check if the character is the one specified, and if it is, we add one to our variable `count`. At the end, we return `count`.

As @Hamatti said below, you do not need to convert to a list first, so here is a simplified version of the code:

```
def frequency(char, sentence):
    count = 0
    for k in sentence:
        if k.lower() == char.lower():
            count+=1
    return count
```

**EDIT:**

If the sentence is imported as a piece of text from a url, use the following code:

```
sentence = urllib.urlopen('myamazingurl.com').read()
def frequency(char, sentence):
    count = 0
    for k in sentence:
        if k.lower() == char.lower():
            count+=1
    return count
```

Then continue as needed. All this does is assigns the variable `sentence` to the text in the url. You can also assign sentence within the `frequency` function, if you will always be pulling from the same url. For that, use the following code:

```
def frequency(char):
    count = 0
    sentence = urllib.urlopen('myamazingurl.com').read()
    for k in sentence:
        if k.lower() == char.lower():
            count+=1
    return count
```

Comment: You don't actually need to convert the string to a list. Strings are iterable as-is so you can just do `for k in sentence`

Comment: Is there any way to use this if the sentence is an imported piece of text from a url lib? Thanks!

Comment: Edited to answer your question :)

Answer (score 1):

You can alter this if you don't want two parameters, but it's probably better to use two in this case.

```
def frequency(c, sentence):
    count = 0
    for character in sentence:
        if (c.lower() == character.lower()):
            count += 1
    return count
```

>>> frequency('c', 'ccc')

>>> 3

Note that I used the `lower()` method to make the comparison case-insensitive.

Comment: Thanks! But, the piece of text used is an import of a url lib, so I need to use 1 parameter only...

Comment: If you need a function you can continuously call but only with one parameter, you have to set up a global variable or some other way to access either the character or the string to use. Otherwise how will the function know what the other parameter is?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) in the [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) module.

```
import collections

def frequency(char, string):
    string = string.lower()
    count = collections.Counter(string)
    return count[char]
```

Ideally, `string = string.lower()` should be omitted and you should pass the string already lower-cased if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

```
pieceoftext.lower().count('t')
```

or

```
frequency = lambda c, s=pieceoftext: s.lower().count(c)
frequency('t')                  # returns 2
frequency('t', pieceoftext)     # returns 2
frequency('t', 'tttt')          # returns 4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def frequency(c,sentance):
    return sum([c==ch for ch in sentance])
```

is how I would do it ... if I wasnt going to use count anyway